# How to isolate a roof

Tags: insulation, roof

This house has a roof with reinforced concrete beams and ceramic tiles. It's located in Castelo Branco, central interior Portugal, which can get very cold in the winter nights and very hot in the summer days.

*The roof currently looks like:*

[image: Attic]

*It only looks bare in the attic, is a small portion of the roof, currently the rest is covered with wood planks that will be removed when the project starts*

[Attic video with better lighting](https://youtu.be/jyqdPqW9-uI):

[image: Attic GIF]

Ideally the attic will be open as shown on the model below, the attic being the brown platform.

[image: House model]

And if it matters here is the roof shape

[image: Roof]

---

I have been reading about how to isolate the roof and concluded that I should have at least 3 layers:

- Impermeable canvas,

*keep any water leak on the outside and prevent airflow*

Current choice: Polyethylene geotextile fabric.

- Isolating material,

*Provides the thermal buffer*

Current choice: XPS boards 50mm thick (extruded polystyrene)

- Cover

*Protect the isolating material from the inside*

Current choice: Simple plaster boards (13mm).

---

While reading I saw many people focusing on R-Values, here I don't have to comply with any legislation so I am just looking to get the best isolation for the least money.

Due to comments I used [this calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/construction/insulation) and got a R-value of 10 for the insulation layers mentioned above.

---

Currently I am not entirely sure how I would attach any of this to the roof.

*I read that I could carefully drill the concrete beams, that would not impact its strength if it doesn't drill into structural iron rods on the inside, but I wanna avoid that at all cost.*

The main idea is to hook into the concrete beams and then attach the materials to the hooks.

*As shown on the following picture although inverted*

[image: Example]

But there are wood boards on the roof outside the attic that are used to attach the wood planks (with nails) that make cover for the roof on the living area, this could be used to attach the insulation.

---

Are there obvious flaws on the choices made?

I'm looking for guidance on a general level, could be just material choice, layer design, material attachment or all the above, depending on your expertise.

Note: Keep in mind that any insulation is better than none, currently air is free to move, even in the covered part of the roof, with the wood planks, there are some cracks and a large hole, and the attic is only separated from the living area by a slim plywood and a hole as a door. So if you have different suggestion altogether let me know!

It's also noted the fact that the roof might not take the extra weight, is definitely something to consider since *roof is better than no roof* and I will have people looking into it before I do any work.

Comment: where in the world are you?  Are you sure the beams are concrete?  Concrete is a lousy choice for roof beams. Also you pic is very dark and shows very little detail.  Please provide a better pic.

Comment: Are you going to use the attic as a living space?  If not then you just need to insulate the floor/ceiling of the living space below.  R-values relate to heat lost/heat gain in a space, most non living use attics just need ventilation

Comment: What is your climate? Regardless of lack of legislation, R-values can make a large difference to your building comfort and operating expense if you either heat or cool (or both) the building.

Comment: The house is in portugal, its a region that gets minus temperatures at night in winter and hot by day in summer, the attic photo is only reference due to the visibility of the bare roof, I intend to open up the attic "wall" (its slim plywood) and replace with curtains for easy acces to that storage location. Right now I dont have better lighted photo, but if its not concrete its a regular roofing material similar to concrete, english is not my native language.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I could try to calculate the R-Value, but what I meant is that I want to isolate the roof as well as I can within the budget, the roof is the only concern since the walls are 70cm thick schist stone and concrete. windows will be changed in the future.

Comment: @RMDman I found a video that has better light, I added a youtube link and a gif with the same video

Comment: I think it's difficult for people outside a country to make product choices, even product classes.  I don't think there are a huge number of Portugese users of this site unfortunately.    Do you have any neighbors who have built roofs recently?   Are there regions of the country near you with similar climate but where there *are* building regulations you could use for guidance?  Does the government have a department, with a web site, that offers guidance?  I don't speak Portugese but I see there is a department of "energy transition"?  Maybe they have some documentation?

Comment: I dont understand what would be the difference between countries, I do know two of my neighbours are fixing their house, one so far has used a common shed roof with built in foam insulation but i didn't get the change to speak with him yet to know his future plans. The other had the same roofing piled on the street waiting for installation, didn't know it was a thing to use such roofs. I will have the chance to speak with them next month. Regarding regulations I can look for it, but what I am looking is for best practices, if the material is wrongfully chosen or arranged and advices in general

Comment: Best choice of material depends on availability that varies from country to country (what is made or imported and how it is marketed and sold) and on the common practice and skills of local workers.  Regulation is often a good guide to best practice.  Don't be *too* contemptuous of regulations.   You don't need to follow them blindly, especially if they are not in force where you are.   But you can imagine that some of the regulations in places near you are based on best practices, or what SHOULD be best practices, and if you have no other guide, it's a good starting point.

Comment: I am not against any regulations, I just dont have access and I was informed that I dont have to comply with anything for this project. I made a quick search for regulations or guides but I didn't find. Either way as I mention I am looking to do as best as I can with what I have, hence the question on this Q&A website, just checking if someone has knowledge on the subject that can detect any flaw, or provide additional advice. I know with my search that there are several diferent ways to achieve this, ignoring the R value would just simplify answers keeping them more generic

Comment: if it helps, on an answer just saying "doing this instead of that would raise insulation or r-value" or even suggesting a new material , if its not available I can see equivalent or disregard due to lack on my area..

Comment: Honestly, I'm unsure of the question. Are you looking for recommendations about the insulation (isolation) material? Are you looking for recommendations about how to attach it to the structure? Are you looking for overall guidance on a plan (which seems vaguely described)? I understand English isn't your 1st language (you've done well!), but it's still unclear what you're after.

Comment: I edited the question, hope is more clear now

Answer (score 2):

I interpret your question the way that you aren't sure on how to improve your roof, and now you look for ideas and confirmation of your current plan.

As much as you'd want to avoid it, for structural work I'd get help from an expert in this matter. Reusing the current load-bearing structure (pre-stressed concrete bars in horizontal layment for the roofing is something new for me) with an new, possible heavier roof sounds too risky for my liking.

Many jurisdictions have also some incentives (tax deductions, state contributions, cubature bonus etc.) to motivate people to renovate by the book. I can imagine that this also could be an possibility for you.

Speaking from personal experience: Relatively to the current building costs, it was very cheap to hire an licensed technician. He inspected my house, made suggestions on how to improve it, helped me navigate the red tape and made all the paperwork for compliance plus contributions.

**A good advice I got at the beginning of my building project**

"Don't do it piecemeal, either do it completely or don't do it now"

**Update**

I'll make a couple of points, but I doubt I'll be able to organize this coherently

Drilling the concrete "beams" is an no-go. It isn't only the steel in the "beams" that provide strength, but also the concrete. Better clamp them, or use wire.

The "bad insulation is better then no insulation" is a fallacy. Bad insulation can lead to moisture and mold problems.

Perhaps, just as an brainstorm idea, see this as an repair: Replace the tiles, plug all the holes and do the great overhaul later. You can reuse the tiles when you do it thorough.

Also the "wind load is of no concern" is a fallacy: Once you touch it, you are responsible for everything that happens. Therefor get someone in authority to check it.

I have no insight in your local code and regulation, but at my place an invoice for "maintenance of the load bearing roof structure" from an licensed timber framer is good ammunition for an eventual legal battle, as he is now the responsible one. Try to leave a paper trail for the things that are in your favor.

Comment: Its not out of question, thanks for the recommendations, I have looked into a environmental fund that helps with costs into renovating insulation in a house, not sure i will get that since it ends up at the 30th this month. By roof you mean just the insolation layers mentioned right? you think it could be too heavy? that's something to consider, although the roof is about 15/20 years old, didn't think the light weight insulation could cause considerable stress on the structure. vote up either way thanks for the advice

Comment: With roof I intended all the layers. I can't speculate if your future roof would be too heavy. I just wanted to say that if you are changing it, have someone in authority look over it.

Comment: I understand. thanks

Comment: @Barreto I know that Portugal is mostly coastal so you probably don't get a lot of snow load, but wind load is definitely something to consider. Any addition to the weight on the roof needs to be carefully considered to avoid the roof becoming the floor. :(

Comment: No, snow load is basically 0, there is snow from time to time but not in great quantities as far as I am aware. wind could be very strong in the area but this is in the middle of a village and the house is lower than all others around so I guess its not so bad.

Comment: Regarding the edit, I plan to do it completely. I am just not able to raise the budget so I wanna make sure the choices I make will be appropriate. I feel people wanted to answer at first but then thought would be a liability to answer due to what is at stake. but this is really to learn. I am not going to rush into anything to be clear. and dont mark this as answer because well its not answering, its good advice though.

Comment: I wouldn't "guess" that the wind load is lower. A few extra spent now on doing it _right_ will be a _lot_ saved in the future when it holds up to far more wind than you think will come your way.

Comment: Thanks for the update, when i said "bad insulation" i meant less thickness not bad composition. I guess the point of the question was exactly to avoid that kind of bad insulation that would cause mold and would last less even if it would have less r value it could be well done. And the tiled are all in good shape. Its a recent roof